# How can I remove bitnami banner on WordPress site?

Tags: wordpress, banner, bitnami

I installed WordPress using Bitnami and now I have the Bitnami banner in the lower right corner of the page on that WordPress site. How can I remove it?

Comment: I can't change the theme. We have a specific theme that we need to use, so I can't just switch to whole new theme, since that would require whole css and html migration. So changing the theme is out of the question.

Comment: inspect that element, add `display:none;` into style.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Milap, I think I will just use that as a temporary solution. I would love that sign not to be appearing at all though, since bitnami and wordpress are not paid services.

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic Can you please help me with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48171755/aws-launchpad-on-bitnami

Comment: Think you should mark 2nd one as correct answer so that it displays up. It's the easiest one...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Running the bnconfig script threw an error, it didn't work, what did work at last I found is this:
https://community.bitnami.com/t/cannot-remoe-the-bitnami-info-banner-for-a-wordpress-multisite/29988

So, comment this line (add # at the beginning) or delete it:
Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/banner.conf"

in file
/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-app.conf

Comment: Here's where to stop and restart the bitnami apache server on windows: [Manage server tab of the bitnami interface](https://imgur.com/vjwCVJw)

Comment: On Windows the line to comment was line 571 Include "C:\Bitnami\wordpress-5.2.3-0/apps/bitnami/banner/conf/banner.conf" changed into # Include "C:\Bitnami\wordpress-5.2.3-0/apps/bitnami/banner/conf/banner.conf"

Answer (score 167):

Bitnami developer here.

The Bitnami info page provides information about the installed application resources as well as useful links to documentation. It is accessible by clicking in the Bitnami banner in the right bottom corner.

In case you want to remove the banner, you will just need to SSH into your machine and then execute the following command:

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/bnconfig --disable_banner 1
```

> Sometimes, it may happen that the bnconfig is disabled so you need to use this command instead
>
> ```
> sudo /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/bnconfig.disabled --disable_banner 1
> ```

Please note that /opt/bitnami is the default installation directory of the Bitnami stack.

Finally, you need to restart Apache.

```
sudo  /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

You will find more information about the Bitnami banner using the following link:

https://docs.bitnami.com/general/components/bninfo/

EDIT:
It might happen that you moved the bnconfig tool when configuring the domain for your WordPress site. Do you have any bnconfig.disabled file in the `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress` directory? If so, please use that file when running the command above.

Regarding the banner, you can remove it manually by running the following command

`sudo touch /opt/bitnami/apps/bitnami/banner/disable-banner`

Apache looks for that file when adding the banner and it disables the banner if the file exists.

Comment: Thanks Mr Jota, btw if this banner usefull for webmaster it should only show up to Admin of the website not the visitor...

Comment: Hi, yes, we configure the banner to be displayed only in the admin interface and not in all the web pages but there are some apps in which our configuration doesn't fully work. Could you please let us know which Bitnami application are you using?

Comment: Hi Jota, I am using Bitnami Wordpress for Google Cloud

Comment: At the time of this comment, I didn't have to restart Apache.

Comment: Worked on AWS hosted site

Comment: Didn't work for me on LightSail. I didn't have bnconfig. I have shared the solution in my answer stackoverflow.com/a/47500444/1997088

Comment: Hi @Black, it might happen that you moved the bnconfig tool when configuring the domain for your WordPress site. Do you have any bnconfig.disabled file in the `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress` directory? Regarding the banner, you can remove it manually by running the following command ```sudo touch /opt/bitnami/apps/bitnami/banner/disable-banner```. Apache looks for that file when adding the banner and it disables the banner if the file exists. Regards, Jota

Comment: I have wordpress on a lightsail account and the banner was showing on my homepage.

Comment: Hi Kenny, did you run the commands I posted? If the "disable_banner" command doesn't work, please create the `/opt/bitnami/apps/bitnami/banner/disable-banner` file in the instance.

Comment: I will note that the file `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/bnconfig` is hidden by default, so you'll have to `ls -A` to see it. This was very confusing for me when I read the Bitnami tutorial.

Comment: @CarterPape The bnconfig tool is not disabled by default. In our documentation we ask the users to rename it in case they configure the application to use a domain name so the tool doesn't modify that configuration during the next reboot. Let us know if you have any questions.

Comment: @JotaMartos I said *hidden*, as in hidden in the file system. useful to know you discourage renaming it, though; I hadn't done that, but I'm using an AWS package not one of those local packages

Comment: @JotaMartos since you're a bitnami dev, maybe you can answer - who in their right mind wants that there and why is it such an in-depth process to turn it off?!  SURELY no production site should ever have that visible, or am I missing something here?

Comment: @theaceofthespade, we include the banner in the bottom right corner to let the users know how to do basic actions in the solution. For example, if you are a new user who is trying the Bitnami stack for the first time, you will have there the information about how to get the login password or how to access the admin dashboard. We also include the information about how to remove it.

Comment: @JotaMartos That part I understand - what I don't understand is why it is such a pain to disable it.  As far as I can tell, it's for absolute beginners, and yet it requires them to dive in on ssh and command line in order to shut it off?  It just seems like a large disparity, whereas you could easily accomplish the same thing with a wordpress plugin that the user could just uninstall or even disable....

Comment: Well, as you mentioned we have other options like a WordPress' plugin but we have more than 100 apps in the catalog and it's not possible to use a plugin in all of them. We follow the same approach in all our solutions and the users just need to SSH the instance and run some commands to disable it.

Comment: I think I'm more suggesting that any user that needs that much hand holding is going to have a hard time sshing and running that command in the first place, as two of my clients have so far.

Comment: Let's be honest, it's an ad.

Answer (score 37):

The easiest way to do this without getting into the backend is to edit the custom CSS.

In the admin panel, go to 
Appearance -> 
Customize -> 
General General- Main

In the custom CSS section paste

```
#bitnami-banner {display:none;}
```

Comment: Thank you JJ. In my case it was Appearance>Theme Options>General>Custom CSS

Comment: Probably the easiest way, but not the best. The banner would still be loaded and slow down the website. It is better to turn it off. See my post https://stackoverflow.com/a/47500444/1997088

Comment: The question is about Removing not Hiding.

Answer (score 6):

All answers here either did not work or were only hiding the banner. Hiding banner would lead to slower load time than if the banner is disabled.

To disable the banner open `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf` and comment the line Include `/opt/bitnami/apps/bitnami/banner/conf/banner.conf` adding a # before it. (I had it on line 557)

Then restart apache executing:
`sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache`

Comment: On my machine the line to comment was line 571                                                
  `Include "C:\Bitnami\wordpress-5.2.3-0/apps/bitnami/banner/conf/banner.conf"` changed into                                                                                                                           
 `# Include "C:\Bitnami\wordpress-5.2.3-0/apps/bitnami/banner/conf/banner.conf"`

Comment: Thank you. This solution worked for me to also remove the welcome page that was still appearing at /bitnami/index.html after running the bitnami disable script.

Answer (score 3):

Go to app name directory and use ./bnconfig

```
cd /opt/bitnami/apps/app_name

sudo ./bnconfig --disable_banner 1

sudo ./ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

Comment: This was the canonical solution for me. One thing though: I found that the "bnconfig" script and the "ctlscript.sh" scripts were in different spots in my installation. (I'm using Bitnami config for AWS in Jan of 2017) The bnconfig script was in ~/apps/wordpress and the ctlscript.sh was in ~/stack

Except for that nuance - this was a working solution given that I used "sudo" command to have sufficient privilege.

Answer (score 3):

Go into wordpress Appearance > Customize > Custom CSS. Add the following:

```
#bitnami-banner { display: none !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Many people gave answers, I'd recommend you follow the official guide.
Follow the official documenation here: https://docs.bitnami.com/google/how-to/bitnami-remove-banner/

However, bitnami page still stays and this could be a security threat if there are vulnerability scanners looking for bitnami setups. Therefore I recommend you also move the page with the command:

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/bitnami/apps/bitnami/banner/htdocs
```

Answer (score 1):

The simpler way that I have been using for a while now:

Add the following CSS to your website (Add custom CSS from under Appearance->Customize)

```
 #bitnami-banner { 
    display: none; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Much easier way… enter this CSS into the theme settings

```
.bitnami-corner-image { display: none !important; }
```

Done.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to remove that weird logo of bitnami from your precious website is below:

That logo of bitnami is hosted on your own website/server so you need to remove that image from your website. The link of that logo would be in below manner just replace your website domain with "yourwebsite.com" and paste it to search bar of your browser and you will see that logo there.

http://yourwebsite.com/bitnami/images/xcorner-logo.png.pagespeed.ic.6TukXqDtLV.png

Now go to your wordpress site and go to media -> Gallery then find that logo image name there or search via search option and then delete it permanently from your wordpress site.

Answer (score 0):

in wordpress:

navigate to Appearance then customise 
Then add the additional CSS

```
#bitnami-banner { 
    display: none; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below mentioned steps to remove Bitnami info page banner for any hosting

login with wp-admin -> Dashboard -> Appearance -> Customize -> Additional CSS ->

```
#bitnami-banner {
    display:none;
}
```

If above code will not work simply add !important

```
#bitnami-banner {
    display:none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can remove the bitnami banner. First, commenting the banner line in .htaccess file and Second, using Customized CSS for the banner to display: none

https://www.discovertopten.com/remove-bitnami-banner-from-your-website/