# AWS launchpad on Bitnami

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, bitnami

I launched Wordpress stack for AWS launchpad on Bitnami. The instance shows its state as running in the EC2 console. I tried logging in via SSH, it doesn't connect. Also, if I try its public IP in the browser, it shows that the site could not be reached. I'm stuck on it from last 2 hours. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you have a firewall issue when connecting to the instance. I advise you to check if that is the case. In addition, I would also try restarting the instance or launching a new one to double check it.

Comment: But when I create an instance normally without using Bitnami, I am able to SSH into it. And why is it that it shows site could not be reached when I type public IP in my browser? Because I have launched the Wordpress stack, I should see the sample wordpress site on typing the public IP in the browser. Isn't it?

Comment: This error is really weird, that is why I would like you to retry launching the instance again. I would like to double check if it a random fail in AWS.

Comment: In that case, I'd like to verify my procedure as well: 1.) I got to https://aws.bitnami.com/ and sign in with bitnami. 2.) licked on launching the wordpress account 3.) After signing in to the bitnami vault, I need to add the cloud account. I use this to do that (https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/get-started-launchpad/#step-2-generate-an-aws-access-key-and-secret) . 4.) After adding, I select region etc for my EC2 instance. And then create. I hope I'm not missing anything.

Comment: And if it is for any use, whenever I try to launch, the progress is stuck at 99% for around 5-6 mins. I launched one compute engine on Google Cloud as well, but it launches smoothly.

Comment: It's already been 10 mins that it's stuck at 99%. My instance shows running on the EC2 console though. Now it showed this message , "We're sorry, but something went wrong. We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly." and when I refreshed, it shows status as running

Comment: I download the pem key, using public IP and username as ec2-user, SSH is not working. The IP is not reachable in the browser.